# Generalised associativity for absolutely convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

It is well-known that if $\sum_na_n$ is an absolutely convergent real series, then the sum remains unchanged under any permutation of $\mathbb N$, so one can reasonably define for a countable set $I$ the sum $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$, provided the terms are either $\geq0$ (in which case the sum is defined in $[0,\infty])$ or $\sum_i|a_i|<\infty$ (summed in any order).

For such **positive** sums, a kind of generalised associativity holds: it can be readily shown that if $I=\bigsqcup_nI_n$ is a partition of $I$, then $\sum_{i\in I}a_i<\infty$ if and only if $s_n=\sum_{j\in I_n}a_j<\infty$ for every $n$ and $\sum_ns_n<\infty$, and moreover $\sum_{i\in I}a_i=\sum_ns_n$. Now the notes I am reading claim the exact same statement holds for absolutely convergent sums and I can clearly see that the forward direction does, but I don't understand the converse
$$\sum_{j\in I_n}|a_j|,\sum_n|s_n|<\infty\implies\sum_{i\in I}|a_i|<\infty.$$
By the positive case, it would be enough to show that $\sum_n\sum_{j\in I_n}|a_j|<\infty$, however I don't see why this should follow from $\sum_{j\in I_n}|a_j|<\infty$ and $\sum_n|\sum_{j\in I_n}a_j|<\infty$.

**Addendum**: Actually, now that I think about it, this is patently false, since if you take the series $1,-1,1,-1,\dots$ over $\mathbb N$ and use the partition $\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}\cup\cdots$, then $\sum_{j\in I_n}|a_j|=2$ and $s_n=0$, but the original series most definitely does not converge absolutely. I'm guessing the author of the notes must've overlooked that the converse doesn't hold in case of absolute convergence and just left the statement as is. I'll probably be closing the question now...

Comment: I think the converse says that if the reverse holds for ALL partitions we get an absolute convergent series

Comment: @Conrad that's kind of tautological, no? If this is true, just take the partition $\{i_1\}\cup\{i_2\}\cup\cdots$, then $\sum_ns_n$ converging absolutely literally means the original series converging absolutely.

Comment: Yes agree but that is what I think it's meant as converse here - not sure of course of what it says in the notes you have, but that's the way I would interpret the statement with the forward implication the tricky one

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the OP, the converse looks to be false, since if you take the series $1,-1,1,-1,\dots$ over $\mathbb N$ and use the partition $\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}\cup\cdots$, then $\sum_{j\in I_n}|a_j|=2$ and $s_n=0$, but the original series most definitely does not converge absolutely. I'm guessing the author of the notes must've overlooked that the converse doesn't hold in case of absolute convergence and just left the statement as is.